# What's the difference between the use of a .dbc file and a .cfg file? Is there a way to convert between them?

Tags: config, can-bus

I have a .cfg file describing a CAN-enabled device. For my CAN interface to access the network, I need it in the .dbc format. Could these formats describe the same thing? I understand that a .dbc describes messages while a .cfg is for initial setup, but is it possible they could be used interchangeably? I haven't been able to find any conversion tools between them, but if they describe the same thing, I could try to write one.

EDIT:
I misunderstood what the files were intended for. The .cfg was for CANalyzer setup in general, not specifically to describe messages like in a .dbc

Comment: By .cfg, do you mean a CANoe config file?

Comment: .cfg could be any tool-specific format, it's not standardized and might not contain what you think. It could be GUI setting preferences etc.